# How can I use the filter function (dplyr) in a for loop?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a macro that I want to return to me the minimum value in the established range on the data frame. So I did that

```
for (i in 36:39) {
  a <- emi_sigma1 %>% filter(between(emi_sigma$V1, i, i + 0.15)) 
  b <- a %>% slice_min(emi_sigma1$V2)
  print(b)
  
  i == i + 0.15
  
}
```

The expected result should be 20 lines corresponding the 20 min values in each range, but the macro returns me only 3 lines and two of them are empty. I already test the function outside the loop and it worked. Any guess?

Comment: It's hard to tell without your data or a reproducible example but it is not so clear what you are trying to do with the i ==i +.15 at the end ? 
Check what happens with a print(i) : the loop is running for i in 36:39, so i = {36,37,38,39}.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you wish to achieve. Could you put a sample dataset so we can run this function?

From my understanding, you may want to do:

```
for(i in seq_along(36, 39-0.15, by = 0.15)) {
  a <- emi_sigma1 %>% filter(between(emi_sigma$V1, i, i + 0.15)) 
  b <- a %>% slice_min(emi_sigma1$V2)
  print(b)
}
```

or:

```
# Initiate i
i = 36
while (i<39) {
  a <- emi_sigma1 %>% filter(between(emi_sigma$V1, i, i + 0.15)) 
  b <- a %>% slice_min(emi_sigma1$V2)
  print(b)
  
  i = i + 0.15
}
```